# CSS/Javascript: Keep a div size based on container size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div which contains 2 divs, one has fixed height. 
I want to make sure that the 2nd div's height is exactly as much as the height of the container div minus the other div's height. This height can't be manually set because it's often resized.

```
<div id="container" style="height: 50%"> 
<div id="header" style="height: 30px;"> 
</div> 
<div id="content"> 
</div> 
</div>
```

i have tried with jquery on resize but i think i wrote something wrong:

```
$(document).on("resize", "#container", function (event) {
    $('#content').height($('#container').height()-$('#header').height());
});
```

Is there any way (Javascript, CSS) to achieve this?

Comment: Does the header have to be `30px` exactly?

Comment: Yes it has to be 30px. And height 100% would make it bigger than the container by 30px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem seems to be that you have to size the element initially and then keep listening to the resize event:

```
function handleResize() {  
   $('#content').height($('#container').innerHeight()-$('#header').height()); 
}

$(window).on("resize", handleResize);

handleResize();
```

Also, the resize event should be attached directly to the window.

Otherwise, I recommend the use of `innerHeight()` for the container as that takes into account padding.

Also I made some fixes to your CSS for this to fully work:

```
#container {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 50%;
}
```

See full fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/kjcY9/1/

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to the jQuery method is CSS Flexbox:

```
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#content {
  flex: 1;
}
```

See the [demo](http://jsbin.com/uYOSujU/1/). Unfortunately, this will only work in browsers supporting the latest Flexbox syntax. (http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox) Backward compatible code is possible using old syntaxes as well, but will be sightly more involved. See David Storey's article at http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/22/centering-elements-with-flexbox/ for more on how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I have a pure CSS solution for you,
Check out that [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GnZfU/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    height: 300px; /*Whatever fixed height you want*/
}
#container:before {
    content:'';
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}
#header {
    height: 30px;/*Whatever fixed height you want, or not fixed at all*/
    background-color: red;
}
#content {
    background-color: blue;
    /*No height spesified*/
}
#content:after {
    content:'';
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
```